# How can I wrap page numbers from the_posts_pagination in WordPress into my own div?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In WordPress, I'm using `the_posts_pagination` to spit out prev/next buttons and page numbers in between. I don't like how WordPress spits out its own markup when I'd like to group certain elements into divs.

This is my current code:

PHP

```
<?php the_posts_pagination( array(
   'mid_size' => 2,
   'prev_text' => __( 'Previous Page', 'textdomain' ),
   'next_text' => __( 'Next Page', 'textdomain' ),
   'screen_reader_text' => ( '' )
) ); ?>
```

It spits out this:

HTML

```
<nav class="navigation pagination" role="navigation">
        <div class="nav-links">
        <a class="prev page-numbers" href="#">Prev Page</a>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="#">1</a>
        <span class="page-numbers current">2</span>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="">3</a>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="">4</a>
        <a class="next page-numbers" href="">Next Page</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I'd like the ability to make it look like this:

```
<nav class="navigation pagination" role="navigation">
        <div class="nav-links">
        <a class="prev page-numbers" href="#">Prev Page</a>
        <div class="page-numbers-container">
             <a class="page-numbers" href="#">1</a>
             <span class="page-numbers current">2</span>
             <a class="page-numbers" href="">3</a>
             <a class="page-numbers" href="">4</a>
        </div>
        <a class="next page-numbers" href="">Next Page</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Even if I could wrap the next and previous links in a div that'd be great too. I don't want to have to edit anything from the core WordPress files. Would I need to write a function?

EDIT

This is in my index.php

```
<?php the_posts_pagination( wp_custom_pagination(['prev_text' => __( 'Previous Page', 'textdomain' ), 'next_text' => __( 'Next Page', 'textdomain' )])); ?>
```

This is what I put inside the functions.php

```
function wp_custom_pagination($args = [], $class = 'pagination') {

            if ($GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages <= 1) return;

            $args = wp_parse_args( $args, [
                'mid_size'           => 2,
                'prev_next'          => false,
                'prev_text'          => __('Older posts', 'textdomain'),
                'next_text'          => __('Newer posts', 'textdomain'),
                'screen_reader_text' => __('Posts navigation', 'textdomain'),
            ]);

            $links     = paginate_links($args);
            $next_link = get_previous_posts_link($args['next_text']);
            $prev_link = get_next_posts_link($args['prev_text']);
            $template  = apply_filters( 'navigation_markup_template', '
            <nav class="navigation %1$s" role="navigation">
                <h2 class="screen-reader-text">%2$s</h2>
                <div class="nav-links">%3$s<div class="page-numbers-container">%4$s</div>%5$s</div>
            </nav>', $args, $class);

            echo sprintf($template, $class, $args['screen_reader_text'], $prev_link, $links, $next_link);

        }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[the_posts_pagination()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_posts_pagination/) uses [paginate_links()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/) which has no filter to alter the output as you want.

So, let's create a custom pagination template:

```
function the_so37580965_wp_custom_pagination($args = [], $class = 'pagination') {

    if ($GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages <= 1) return;

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, [
        'mid_size'           => 2,
        'prev_next'          => false,
        'prev_text'          => __('Older posts', 'textdomain'),
        'next_text'          => __('Newer posts', 'textdomain'),
        'screen_reader_text' => __('Posts navigation', 'textdomain'),
    ]);

    $links     = paginate_links($args);
    $next_link = get_previous_posts_link($args['next_text']);
    $prev_link = get_next_posts_link($args['prev_text']);
    $template  = apply_filters( 'the_so37580965_navigation_markup_template', '
    <nav class="navigation %1$s" role="navigation">
        <h2 class="screen-reader-text">%2$s</h2>
        <div class="nav-links">%3$s<div class="page-numbers-container">%4$s</div>%5$s</div>
    </nav>', $args, $class);

    echo sprintf($template, $class, $args['screen_reader_text'], $prev_link, $links, $next_link);

}
```

Try it out. Also, take a look at [paginate_links()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/) function, there're many more arguments you may need.

Comment: how am I calling this in my index.php?

Comment: @DarrenBachan You just need to replace the `the_posts_pagination(...)` code with `the_so37580965_wp_custom_pagination(['prev_text' => __( 'Previous Page', 'textdomain' ), 'next_text' => __( 'Next Page', 'textdomain' )])`. That's all.

Comment: I edited the OP to show you what I'm doing, I got a fatal error saying undefined function wp_custom_pagination(). I did change up a bit of it, the so37580965 was too much, unless it's necessary.

Comment: In my functions.php

Comment: Apologies, I don't know what happened, I reloaded the page and it just started working. Thanks!

Comment: If I'm defining the arguments in the function, why do I need to repeat it when calling that function?

Comment: http://www.stepyouraimup.com/blog/page/2/ it's duping the buttons actually, how do I fix that?

Comment: I'm only calling it once though, Is it because I'm passing the args into the_posts_pagination again?

Comment: @DarrenBachan Just use the function directly, don't wrap it inside `the_posts_pagination()`. Remove `the_post_pagination` completely.

Comment: Ah I see the problem, okay I get how I was calling it in twice. I wish the option to move this to chat would appear, I would like to ask you a few more questions. I am trying to figure out how to add a .prev class to prev post title and .next on next post title. Those seemed to have gotten stripped in this new function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113786/discussion-between-darren-bachan-and-dan).